# How to use instaSharper share media method?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I am using InstaSharper Package(https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper) for uploading image to Instagram, however now I want to share those media(photos and videos) on connected Facebook page.
The signature of this share media method is as follows -

```
Task<IResult<InstaDirectInboxThreadList>> ShareMedia(string mediaId, InstaMediaType mediaType, params string[] threads);
```

I am not sure, how to get the last parameter Threads. I searched all over the internet but this is being not used by people.

Can anyone help ?
PS- I am also not 100% sure that this method will post the stuff on Facebook, But this is the only relevant method I found.